# Using Tkinter libraray in python on runpod.io throws an error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a pretty basic tkinter eg. on a runpod.io server running pytorch -

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

print("Running1")
# Create a new window
window = tk.Tk()

# Set the window title
window.title("My GUI")
print("Running")
# Create a label
label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello, World!")
```

This consistently throws an error
`TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

I have tried the solutions of adding matplotlib or export display variable, but nothing works as its a remote server.  Is there a solution that can be applied in a runpod.io environment?

Comment: You can use `Xvfb` i guess.

Comment: Does the server have a `GUI` screen?

Comment: No runpods created do not provide a GUI, it does not provide for a screen unfortunately, its a direct Jupyter notebook running on the remote allocated server.  Also I would need to run the python of a base linux setup without any GUI dependency, as it will be running on flask server and be accessible through any web browser.